# Azure DocumentDB , Search In Dictionary with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, azure, azure-cosmosdb, nosql

Hi I am getting an error while using

```
query = query.Where(r => r.Features.ContainsValue(fuelType));
```

Here is my Model

```
public class VehicleResponse 
        {
            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
            public string Id { get; set; }

            public Vehicle Vehicle { get; set; }

            public List<string> PhotoUrls { get; set; }

            public string VideoUrl { get; set; }

            public Dictionary<string, string> Features { get; set; }

            public List<string> Equipments { get; set; }

            public VehicleResponse()
            {
                this.PhotoUrls = new List<string>();
            }
        }
```

DocumentDB is not supporting "ContainsValue" method.  So how should I change my LINQ query ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define your features like this:

```
  "Features": {
    "TKey": "TK1",
    "TValue": "TV1"
  }
```

You could change it to :
query = query.Where(r => r.Features["TKey"].Contains("T"));

You could read the [documents](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-sql-query/) to get more information.

Comment: Thanks It worked !  BTW do you have any idea about how to do the same thing for List<string> ?

Comment: It is similar to a array, you could use Contains directly, like `Where(f => f.Equipments.Contains("E"))`

Comment: It wasnt a clean result coming from Contains in List<string> , I just append list items to raw string , better result.

Comment: Show me your JSON document for the VehicleResponse